# pagination variable and other variables are conflict in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

in my admin panel of online shopping project i am displaying a product and it's code like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php
include('config.php');
$query=mysql_query("select * from product_tbl");
    $totalrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if(isset($_REQUEST['page']))
    {
        $page=$_REQUEST['page'];
        echo "page=$page";
        $page=$page*10;
        $pagquery=mysql_query("select * from product_tbl limit $page,10");
    }         
    else
    {
        $page=0;
    $pagquery=mysql_query("select * from product_tbl limit 0,10");
    }
    echo "Product Table";
echo "<table border=1 width=100%>";
echo "<tr><th>";
echo "Prod ID";
echo "</th><th>";
echo "Cat ID";
echo "</th><th>";
echo "Com ID";
echo "</th><th>";
echo "Product Name";
echo "</th><th>";
echo "Product Price";
echo "</th><th>";
echo "Product Discount";
echo "</th><th>";
echo "Product Desc";
echo "</th><th>";
echo "Product Image";
echo "</th><th>";
echo "Status";
echo "</th></tr>";
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($pagquery))
    {
       if($r['prod_status'] == 0) {
        //$sqlup="UPDATE product_tbl set prod_status=!prod_status where prod_id='".$r['prod_id']."'";
        $im='<a href="product.php?false='.$r["prod_id"].'"><img src="images/red.jpg" height="28" width="28"></a>';
    }
    else{
        $im='<a href="product.php?true='.$r["prod_id"].'"><img src="images/green.jpg" height="30" width="30"></a>';
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['false'])) {
        $updt=mysql_query("update product_tbl set prod_status=1 where prod_id='".$_REQUEST['false']."'");
        header('location:product.php?page='.$page);
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['true'])) {
        $updt=mysql_query("update product_tbl set prod_status=0 where prod_id='".$_REQUEST['true']."'");
        header('location:product.php?page='.$page);
    }
    echo "<tr><td><center>".$r['prod_id']."</center></td><td><center>".$r['cat_id']."</center></td><td><center>".$r['com_id']."</center></td><td><center>".$r['prod_name']."</center></td><td><center>".$r['prod_price']."</center></td><td><center>".$r['prod_discount']."</center></td><td><center>".$r['prod_desc']."</center></td><td><center><img src=".$r['prod_img']." height=100 width=100></center></td><td><center>".$im."</center></td></tr>";
    }
    $page=0;
    echo "<tr colspan=3>";
    for($i=0;$i<=$totalrows;$i+=10)
    {
        echo "<a href=product.php?page=".$page++.">  ".$page."</a>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<br/>";
 ?>
 <br><br>
    <a href="backup_insert_prod.php"><input type="submit" value="Insert"></a>
    <a href="update_prod.php"><input type="submit" value="Update"></a>
    <a href="delete_prod.php"><input type="submit" value="Delete"></a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and this code displaying in browser like this

[image]

all the data come from database MYSQL.in status column i am displaing green button for status on(1) and red button for status off(0) and it is in image tag.
and if i click on green button it will change to red button and change status to off(0) in database or viceversa...

my problem is when i am not in page 1 and click the button it will change the image and status in database for that product but, pagination comes to first page or say page=0.it happens for all the pages instead of page 1.i want to stay on the same page.please give your suggestion.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the links of those buttons so they'll include the current `page` parameter in the URL.

**Notice:** Please consider to define a new variable (with more relative name) for holding the x10 result of the page value.

So instead of having:

```
$page=$_REQUEST['page'];
echo "page=$page";
$page=$page*10;
```

You would have:

```
$page=$_REQUEST['page'];
echo "page=$page";
$start=$page*10;
```

And of course that you'll have to update your query (simply replace the variable).

After that you can simply do the following:

Replace:

```
   if($r['prod_status'] == 0) {
    //$sqlup="UPDATE product_tbl set prod_status=!prod_status where prod_id='".$r['prod_id']."'";
    $im='<a href="product.php?false='.$r["prod_id"].'"><img src="images/red.jpg" height="28" width="28"></a>';
}
else{
    $im='<a href="product.php?true='.$r["prod_id"].'"><img src="images/green.jpg" height="30" width="30"></a>';
}
```

With:

```
if($r['prod_status'] == 0) {
    //$sqlup="UPDATE product_tbl set prod_status=!prod_status where prod_id='".$r['prod_id']."'";
    $im='<a href="product.php?false='.$r["prod_id"].'&page='.$page.'"><img src="images/red.jpg" height="28" width="28"></a>';
}  else{
    $im='<a href="product.php?true='.$r["prod_id"].'&page='.$page.'"><img src="images/green.jpg" height="30" width="30"></a>';
}
```

If you don't want to change the variable's name as I mentioned above ("notice:") you can simply write `&page='.($page/10).'`. However, it's a bad practice and not recommended.

The reason that it's working on the first page is because you have the following condition:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['page']))
```

So if the `page` parameter isn't set - you set it in your code to be `0` (first page).

Comment: with this changes when i am on page=3 and if i click the button,it will go to page=30...for page=2 it will go to page=20....page is multipling by 10 or whatever...please,give me more help.

Comment: I missed that line: `$page=$page*10;`. I have to say that it's a bad practice using the `page` variable to hold that value (semantic reasons). I would advise to use another variable name for that purpose, for instance: `$limit`. The short solution is to replace `&page='.$page.'` with `&page='.($page/10).'`

Comment: i had to replace it for if (isset($_REQUEST['false'])) and if (isset($_REQUEST['true']))....now i get it....thanx for your help...

Comment: but,with $start=$page*10; pagination select 1 to 10 rows for page 1...and then for page 2 it is selecting 2 to 11 and for page 3 it is selecting 3 to 12 and so on...

Comment: You'll have to change all of your code accordingly, otherwise - as you've mentioned, you'll get into some weird situations.